# Pandas - match two columns from two data frames and create new column in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

df1

```
Srlno id  image
1      3    image1.jpg
2      3    image2.jpg
3      3    image2.jpg
```

df2

```
Srlno  id   image
1       1   image1.jpg
2       2   image2.jpg
3       3   image3.jpg
```

I want to match both the data frames based on the column Image and return the Id from df2 to df1 as a newcolumn.  The image names in df2 are unique whereas the image names in df1 has lot of duplicates.  I want to retain the duplicate image names but fill in the correct id for each image from df2.

The expected output is :

```
Srlno id  image          newids
1      3    image1.jpg     1
2      3    image2.jpg     2
3      3    image2.jpg     2
```

I tried with

```
df1['newids'] = df1['image'].map(df2.set_index('image')['id'])
```

This returns  an error InvalidInvexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects')  I understand the duplicates in df1 is creating this error...but don't know how to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for get only unique `image` value for `map`:

```
#default keep first dupe
s = df2.drop_duplicates('image').set_index('image')['id']
df1['newids'] = df1['image'].map(s)

#keep last dupe
s = df2.drop_duplicates('image', keep='last').set_index('image')['id']
df1['newids'] = df1['image'].map(s)

#keep last dupe
d = dict(zip(df2['image'], df2['id']))
df1['newids'] = df1['image'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution with `dict(zip())`

```
df1['newids']=df1.image.map(dict(zip(df2.image,df2.id)))
print(df1)

   Srlno  id       image  newids
0      1   3  image1.jpg       1
1      2   3  image2.jpg       2
2      3   3  image2.jpg       2
```